# kohana/php parse $_FILES vector

Tags: php, forms, file, kohana

i want to parse a $_files vector in order to make a multiple upload.
i try like this:

```
 for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['product_image']);$i++){PRINT_R($_FILES['product_image'][$i]);
```

but it gives me the error:  Undefined offset: 0 in /Users.... etc then the same for 1, 3, etc.
in the form i have: three fields:

```
            <input id="product_image" type="file" name="product_image[]" >          
            <input id="product_image" type="file" name="product_image[]" >          
            <input id="product_image" type="file" name="product_image[]" >
```

i wonder where am i wrong? wht can't i parse the $_files vector?

Comment: Hi, try `print_r($_FILES)` to check if it contains something.

Comment: i have put it, and now gives me the error i have posted. if i give up writing $_FILES['product_image'][$i], and i write only $_FILES['product_image'], it returns the right result. but i need to be able to work with each element of the array.

Comment: just to say $_FILES isn't a vector. it's an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using a foreach loop ?

See [Example 3 for file upload on PHP site](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Pictures:
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </p>
</form>

<?php
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:

Maybe your first loop could work like this:

```
$files_count = count($_FILES['product_image']['error']);
for($i = 0; $i < $files_count; $i++)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: i tried uploading and saving the files using foreach, but strangely enough it only saves me the first upload. code:

foreach ($_FILES["product_image"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["product_image"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, APPPATH . 'media' . '/'.$name);
        $image = Model::factory('image');
        $product_image->image = $name;
     $product_image->product = $product;
     $product_image->save();
        
        
    }
}

Comment: Maybe PHP execution is interrupted at the first loop ?
Could you try for example, just `echo $_FILES["product_image"]["name"][$key];` in the loop ?
If all uploaded file names are displayed, you should look for another PHP error message...

Comment: right, it gives me only the first element. if i remove the if err condition, still the same. i wonder why

Comment: Uh, strange. Could you please show the result of a `print_r($_FILES)` before the loop ? Are you uploading a file in each of the three upload fields ?

Comment: FYI I have to go to bed now ! See you tomorrow :)

Comment: so i have: 
  foreach ($_FILES["product_image"]["name"] as $key => $name) { print_r($_FILES);
  
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["product_image"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, APPPATH . 'media' . '/'.$name);
        $image = Model::factory('image');
        $product_image->image = $name;
     $product_image->product = $product; 
     $product_image->save();

Comment: and at print_r: Array ( [product_image] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => IMG_7412.jpg [1] => IMG_7251.jpg [2] => IMG_7239.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phptVXkwE [1] => ... etc

Comment: problem solved - thanks to you. i loop through the [name] and not the error. works now. (i guess the error was always 0 if i introduced valid files. i don;t know if that was the prob, cause the key was unique) Anyways, thank you very much!